# Cordova ondevice ready not working as it should

Tags: cordova

I've generated a blank new Cordova project (Using WebStorm). For some reason if I want to add event listener (for deviceready) inline, it won't work. How ever using the external file, it works great.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        alert('ondeviceready');
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

This works perfect, the alert will be triggered.

How ever if I include the event listener inline, it won't trigger:

```
 <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady,false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert('ondeviceready');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I also tried pasting the whole index.js as an inline script and neither did that work.

Does anyone have the explanation for this rare cause?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that in the second example, onDeviceReady is not declared yet.
Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('ondeviceready');
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady,false);
</script>
```